# Calling a method of an object that resides within a dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary that contains an `int` and an object of type `Resource`.  The `Resource` object contains a method called `CreateNode()`.  If I write a `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach (var resourcePair in ResourceDictionary)
{
    // call CreateNode() on each Resource object in dictionary pair
}
```

How can I call the `CreateNode()` method on each Resource object in the dictionary?  I've tried the following, but the editor doesn't like it (says "Cannot resolve symbol").  Which is correct since it appears I'm trying to call the `CreateNode` method on the pair instead of the `CreateNode()` method on the object that is part of the pair.

```
foreach (var resourcePair in ResourceDictionary)
{
    resourcePair.CreateNode(ref xElement);
}
```

I just can't figure out how to do this.  Can someone offer a pointer in the right direction?

Comment: What is the type of ResourceDirtionary?

Comment: @Paddy ResourceDictionary is a dictionary that contains an `int` (as the key) and an object of type `Resource`, which is the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
foreach (var resourcePair in ResourceDictionary.Values)
{
    resourcePair.CreateNode(ref xElement);
}
```

You need to specify that you want to access the values (which is your collection of resource objects) otherwise you are just accessing a KeyValuePair that doesnt have a CreateNode method.

Comment: That did the trick!  I'll mark the answer as soon as the timer is up.  Thanks a lot!  I surely appreciate the help.

Comment: You should probably rename the variable from `resourcePair` to something more meaningful, since it's no longer the key-value pair...

Comment: No problem, I had this exact same issue the other day and it had me scratching my head for a good 10 minutes before I had my eureka/doh moment.

Comment: @DanPuzey Good idea, Dan.  I'll be sure to do that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`resourcePair` is a `KeyValuePair<Tkey,TValue>` in your case `KeyValuePair<int,Resource>`

so you need to access the `Value` property in order to call your method:

```
foreach (var resourcePair in ResourceDictionary)
{
    resourcePair.Value.CreateNode(ref xElement);
}
```